# Got a problem with my button after adding BottomNavigator

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout

im new to flutter and i got a problem on my app,

firstly i was creating a button on my "ReminderPage" to navigate to a different page "AddReminder". it works before, so i try to add BottomNavigator in my "MainPage", but when i add a bottom navigatation from "HomePage" to "ReminderPage" all of the sudden the button didnt work, i also have an icon to change the theme, but the button didnt work and the background all of the sudden become blue, i dont know how this error happen so i need help from all of you guys, thank you

here is my "ReminderPage" code

```
import 'package:date_picker_timeline/date_picker_timeline.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/services/notification_services.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/services/theme_services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/ui/theme.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/ui/widgets/add_remindbar.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/ui/widgets/button.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/ui/widgets/add_remindbar.dart';

class ReminderHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReminderHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ReminderHomePage> createState() => _ReminderHomePageState();
}

class _ReminderHomePageState extends State<ReminderHomePage> {
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  var notifyHelper;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    notifyHelper=NotifyHelper();
    notifyHelper.initializeNotification();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: _appBar(),
      backgroundColor: context.theme.backgroundColor,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          _addTaskBar(),
          _addDateBar(),
        ],
        ),
    );
  }
  _addDateBar(){
    return Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
            child: DatePicker(
              DateTime.now(),
              height: 100,
              width: 80,
              initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
              selectionColor: Color(0xFFAAB6FB),
              selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
              dateTextStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color:Colors.grey
                ),
              ),
              dayTextStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color:Colors.grey
                ),
              ),
              monthTextStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color:Colors.grey
                ),
              ),
              onDateChange: (date){
                    _selectedDate=date;
              },
            ),
          );
  }
  _addTaskBar(){
    return Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 5),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(DateTime.now()),
                      style: subHeadingStyle,
                      ),
                      Text("Today", 
                      style: headingStyle,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                MyButton(label: "Add Reminder", onTap: ()=>Get.to(AddReminderPage()))
              ],
            ),
          );
  }

  _appBar(){
    return AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: context.theme.backgroundColor,
      leading: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
            ThemeService().switchTheme();
            notifyHelper.displayNotification(
              title:"Theme Changed!",
              body: Get.isDarkMode?"Activated Light Theme!":"Activated Dark Theme!"
            );

            notifyHelper.scheduledNotification();
        },
        child: Icon(Get.isDarkMode ?Icons.wb_sunny_outlined:Icons.nightlight_round,
        size: 20,
          color:Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.white:Colors.black
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: AssetImage(
            "images/profile.png"
          ),
        ),
        // Icon(Icons.person,
        // size: 20,),
        SizedBox(width: 20,),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

here is my BottomNavigator code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/ui/home_reminder.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/ui/widgets/add_remindbar.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/home_page.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/profile_page.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/settings_page.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/Reminder/ui/theme.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MainPage()));

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  List <Widget> pages = [
    HomePage(),
    SettingPage(),
    ProfilePage()
  ];
  int currentIndex = 0;
  void onTap(int index){
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
        child: pages[currentIndex]
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        onTap: onTap,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: bluishClr,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "Home", icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "Settings", icon: Icon(Icons.settings)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "Profile", icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle)),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and lastly here is my HomePage code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/get_navigation.dart';
import 'Reminder/ui/home_reminder.dart';
import 'Reminder/ui/widgets/button.dart';

void main() {
  // debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(const HomePage());
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Medicine Reminder App'),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                'images/MenuImg.jpg',
                width: 600,
                height: 200,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black)),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ReminderHomePage()),
                );
                },
                child: Text("Button1"),
              ),
              TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black)),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Button2"),
              ),
              TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black)),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text("Button3"),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i really need a help, so every help would mean so much to me, thankyou guys

here is my app working perfectly when i run only the ReminderPage
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqcZp.png

and here's how it look if i run it with BottomNavigationBar (the add reminder button and moon icon cant be clicked)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hVr8.png

Comment: I am little confused which part will I test ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(

  
     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ReminderHomePage())
);
```

Comment: in which code should i put that?

Comment: HomePage -> Button2 -> onPressed

Comment: should i put that in all of my Button?

Comment: Do it for one of them, if it works then put it for others

Comment: i have a red underline error in "push();" it says "1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found."

Comment: of course, it has an error. I just mean add this param 'rootNavigator: true' in of method. pass parameter to push method as you passed it before

Comment: show another red underline in "context" its says "The argument type 'BuildContext' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Route<Object?>'"

Comment: sorry, you're. it was additional & it was deleted

Comment: im sorry but i didnt understand what u mean ma'am

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ReminderHomePage()),
            );
```